# Passing a mixed-type parameters to a function as a pointer, I think

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

this my first time posting here.  Please forgive my inexperience; I'm just learning.

I'm trying to implement a GSL root-finding method, and it requires passing the dependent variable and a struct of parameters to the function.

Here's the parameter struct that gets passed to the function (it's in a .h file):

```
struct SumForces_params
{
double curvature;
struct panel panels[1000];
int lenPanels;
};
```

Here's where I define an instance of the parameters:

```
struct SumForces_params params = {0.0000001, {panels[1000]}, lenPanels};
```

Here's the function:

```
double SumForces(double NAloc, void *params)
{
struct SumForces_params *p = (struct SumForces_params *) params;
double curvature = p->curvature; //works fine
int lenPanels = p->lenPanels; //works fine

struct panel panels = p->panels[1000];
//~ printf("panel 421 location = %g\n", panels[421].Yloc); 
//~ Above line gives this error: SumForces.c:54: error: subscripted value is neither
//~ array nor pointer

double yloc = 0;
yloc = p->panels[421].Yloc;
printf("panel 421 location = %g\n", yloc);
}
```

In main, this gives me the expected output:

```
printf("Main Panel 421 loc = %g\n",panels[421].Yloc);
```

But as noted from the function code, struct panel panels = p->panels[1000]; doesn't work, and the output from the second attempt (the last three lines) returns zero.  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my definition of struct panel:

```
struct panel
{
   double strain[136];
   double stress[136];
   double AE[136];
   double Ys;
   double E;
   double Yloc;
   double Area;
   gsl_interp_accel *acc_stress;
   gsl_spline *spline_stress;
   gsl_interp_accel *acc_AE;
   gsl_spline *spline_AE;
};
```

And here is where I define panels as an array of 1000 panel structures:

```
struct panel panels[1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct panel panels = p->panels[1000];
```

`p->panel` is an array of `1000` elements. The last element has index `999` since you start indexing at `0`. So, this particular line invokes UB. You probably want:

```
struct panel panels = p->panels[ 999 ];
```

Comment: Dirk, thank you.  That alleviated the error, but if I then print panels[999].Yloc, I still get zero.  This leads me to believe that where I'm defining the parameter structure, struct SumForces_params params = {0.0000001, {panels[1000]}, lenPanels};  is incorrect.  panels is already defined; am I redefining it here?  Thanks!

Comment: Your initialization for `params` is incorrect. That needs to be fixed. The second element requires an array of `1000` objects of type `panel` whereas you are passing only one (that too an out-of-bounds access) element. Unfortunately, I don't have the definition of `struct panel` to help you.

Comment: Dirk, I edited my original post to show my definition of struct panel and of where i initialized an array of panel structs. thanks!

Comment: @Matt: `panels` objects need a proper initialization function (since there are pointers, member arrays etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler probably understood your syntax in a wrong way (not what you expected), and didn't warn about this:

```
struct SumForces_params params = {0.0000001, {panels[1000]}, lenPanels};
```

I guess from your question that you want to copy the data about panels into `params`. The correct way to do it is like this:

```
    struct SumForces_params params =
    {
        0.0000001,
        {}, // C doesn't have syntax for "put panels here"
        lenPanels
    };
    memcpy(params.panels, panels, sizeof(params.panels));
```